# assigning protocol parameter to object member

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-protocol

In my header file i am defining a class member:

```
id<IAdmobTestSuite>* testSuite;
```

Later i want to assign this variable using this function:

```
- (void) setTestSuite:(id<IAdmobTestSuite>)_testSuite {
if(testSuite == nil) {
    testSuite = _testSuite;
  }
}
```

but here xcode show we this error: "Assigning to 'id IAdmobTestSuite *' from incompatible type 'id IAdmobTestSuite '; take the address with &"

Dont really understand this error, How can i properly assign this member?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id` is a pointer, to fix the error you should remove the `*` in your header

```
id<IAdmobTestSuite> testSuite;
```